# Using asp within Grunt

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, gruntjs, email

I'm developing a WebApp using grunt on a Linux machine. I have a feedback page, with a bunch of form objects on it. I'm trying to get the forms to be read by a FormSubmission.asp so that it sends an email to me whenever feedback is submitted.

In *feedback.html*

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email Body</label>
   <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="commentInput" name="commentInput"></textarea>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
   <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
   <input type="email" class="form-control" name="inputEmail" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Enter email">
</div>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" form="commentInput","inputEmail", 
formaction="FormSubmission.asp">Submit</button>
```

In *FormSubmission.asp*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<%
dim from
from = Request.Form("inputEmail")
dim comment
comment = Request.Form("commentInput")
Set eMail=CreateObject("CDO.Message")
eMail.Subject="Feedback"
eMail.From=from
eMail.To="MyEmail@mydomain.com"
eMail.TextBody=comment
eMail.Send
set eMail=nothing
Response.Write("Done")
%>
</body>
</html>
```

I've followed a lot of the tutorials from We3. I've also downloaded grunt-iisexpress to run IIS on my grunt server. Nothing seems to work. What am I doing wrong? Are there any easier alternatives to asp to send emails?